# How to create a new column with the missing values for a dataset?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am working with a data set of Stores, corresponding Supply Sites and the delivery day (as a number Monday=1, Tuesday=2 etc) combinations in BigQuery SQL of about 70000 rows.

| Store | Supply_Site | Weekday |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 999 | 1 |
| 1000 | 999 | 4 |
| 1000 | 900 | 3 |
| 1000 | 900 | 6 |
| 2000 | 999 | 4 |

From this I am trying to add an additional column that includes the days the delivery is servicing for the respective store and supply site, like this:

| Store | Supply_Site | Weekday | Serviced_Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 999 | 1 | 1,2,3 |
| 1000 | 999 | 4 | 4,5,6,7 |
| 1000 | 900 | 3 | 3,4,5 |
| 1000 | 900 | 6 | 6,7,1`,2` <-- looks missing |
| 2000 | 999 | 4 | 4,5,6,7,1,2,3 |

Not sure where to start where to start with this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider below.

```sql
SELECT Store, Supply_Site, Weekday,
       TRIM(FORMAT('%t',
         CASE
           WHEN end_day IS NOT NULL THEN GENERATE_ARRAY(start_day, end_day) 
           ELSE GENERATE_ARRAY(start_day, 7) || GENERATE_ARRAY(1, first_day - 1)
         END
        ), '[]') AS Serviced_Days
  FROM (
    SELECT *,
           Weekday AS start_day,
           LEAD(Weekday) OVER w0 - 1 AS end_day,
           FIRST_VALUE(Weekday) OVER w0 AS first_day
      FROM Stores
    WINDOW w0 AS (PARTITION BY Store, Supply_Site ORDER BY Weekday)
  );
```

**Query results**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try grouping the data by Store and Supply_Site + concatenating the Weekday values for each group using `STRING_AGG`

use `CASE` to handle the case where the delivery day crosses over the end of the week (if the delivery day is 6 and the following day is 1)

```
SELECT Store, Supply_Site, Weekday,
  CONCAT(
    STRING_AGG(CAST(Weekday AS STRING), ','), ',',
    STRING_AGG(CAST((Weekday + 1) % 7 AS STRING), ',')
  ) AS Serviced_Days
FROM my_table
GROUP BY Store, Supply_Site, Weekday
```

- using `%` to handle the case where the delivery day crosses over the end of the week ((Weekday + 1) % 7 will return 1 if Weekday is 6 -- corresponds to Monday)

ps. the query assumes that the delivery week starts on Monday (Monday is day 1 -- Sunday is day 7)